# Change the colour of specific observations on boxplot using ggplot

Tags: r, ggplot2, colors, boxplot

I have drawn a boxplot, using ggplot, of the discrete daily price returns of the Dow Jones Industrial Average Index from 01 Jan 2000 to 24 March 2020.

In the boxplot, I would like to highlight specific observations in the plot as follows:

1. The most recent observation in the data set. The latest
   observation in the time series is the price return on 24 March 2020
   which is 11.4%. I would like to highlight this observation in the
   chart in a different colour
2. Secondly, I would like to specify a date and colour the specific
   observation on that date in a different colour. For example, I would
   like to choose 16 March 2020 and highlight the observation with
   return -12.9%.

Finally, I would like to add a legend to chart that shows these two observations with the labels “Current” and “16-Mar-20”

Any advice on how to get this output would be most appreciated, thanks!

```
library(rtsdata)
library(dplyr)
library(ggplot2)
library(xts)
library(PerformanceAnalytics)
library(tbl2xts)

price_data = ds.getSymbol.yahoo("^DJI", from = "2000-01-01", to = Sys.Date())
price_data = data.frame(date=index(price_data), coredata(price_data))
price_data = as_tibble(price_data)

closing_price = price_data %>%
  select(date, DJI.Close) %>%
  rename(close = DJI.Close)

return_data = Return.calculate(tbl_xts(closing_price), method = c("discrete"))
return_data = data.frame(date=index(return_data), coredata(return_data))
return_data = as_tibble(return_data)

return_data = return_data %>%
  rename(return_obs = close)

ggplot(data = return_data, aes(x = "", y = return_obs)) + 
  geom_boxplot() + 
  scale_y_continuous(labels = scales::percent_format(accuracy = 1)) + 
  ylab("Daily price return") + 
  xlab("Index") + 
  ggtitle("Boxplot of the Dow Jones Index \n (01 Jan 2000 to 24 March 2020)")
```

[image]

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Add some geom_point layers like so:

```r
library(rtsdata)
library(dplyr)
library(ggplot2)
library(xts)
library(PerformanceAnalytics)
library(tbl2xts)

price_data = ds.getSymbol.yahoo("^DJI", from = "2000-01-01", to = Sys.Date())
price_data = data.frame(date=index(price_data), coredata(price_data))
price_data = as_tibble(price_data)

closing_price = price_data %>%
  select(date, DJI.Close) %>%
  rename(close = DJI.Close)

return_data = Return.calculate(tbl_xts(closing_price), method = c("discrete"))
return_data = data.frame(date=index(return_data), coredata(return_data))
return_data = as_tibble(return_data)

return_data = return_data %>%
  rename(return_obs = close)

data1 <- filter(return_data, date == as.Date("2020-03-24"))
data2 <- filter(return_data, date == as.Date("2020-03-16"))

ggplot(data = return_data, aes(x = "", y = return_obs)) + 
  geom_boxplot() + 
  geom_point(data = data1, color = "red") +
  geom_point(data = data2, color = "green") +
  geom_text(aes(label = date), data = data1, color = "red", hjust = -.1) +
  geom_text(aes(label = date), data = data2, color = "green", hjust = -.1) +
  scale_y_continuous(labels = scales::percent_format(accuracy = 1)) + 
  ylab("Daily price return") + 
  xlab("Index") + 
  ggtitle("Boxplot of the Dow Jones Index \n (01 Jan 2000 to 24 March 2020)")
#> Warning: Removed 1 rows containing non-finite values (stat_boxplot).
```

[image]

<sup>Created on 2020-03-25 by the [reprex package](https://reprex.tidyverse.org) (v0.3.0)</sup>